# Previous element of array not accessible in the current iteration of loop where that array is looped over

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to access an element in an array which was populated with a value in the previous iteration of the loop. However, the previous element is picked up as *undefined* even though logging it in previous iteration gave the correct value.

```
var vars=[];
vars[0] = obj[idmapping[0]];
idmapping[1] = idmapping[1].replace(/[@()]/g, '');
var idmappingarr = idmapping[1].split('=');
var idk = idmappingarr[0];
var idv = idmappingarr[1];

//the below line works
vars[1] = vars[0].find(v => v['identifier']==idv);

for(var m=2;m<idmapping.length;m++){
    if(!idmapping[m].includes("@")){
        vars[m]=vars[m-1][idmapping[m]];
        console.log(JSON.stringify(vars[m]));
    }
    else{
        
        idk = idmapping[m].replace(/[@()]/g, '').split('=')[0];
        idv = idmapping[m].replace(/[@()]/g, '').split('=')[1];
   
        // the below doesn't work and vars[m-1] is read as undefined
        vars[m]=vars[m-1].find(v => v['identifier']==idv); 
        
    }
}

idmapping=[
  'val1',
  '(@identifier=val2)',
  'val3',
  '(@identifier=val4)',
  'val5',
  '(@identifier=val6)'
]

obj={
    "id":"ABC",
    "val1":[
        {
            "identifier":"val2",
            "val3":[
                {
                    "identifier":"val4",
                    "val5":[
                        {
                            "identifier":"val6",
                            "physicalObject":{
                                "description":"",
                                "organization":{
                                    "annualCompanyTurnover":{
                                        "code":"",
                                        "title":""
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: could you please provide a working example of your code? we don't know how your `idmapping` array looks like or your `obj`

Comment: Added sample values of both variables.

Comment: In this loop: `for (var m=2;m<idmapping.length;m++) {...` the initial index is 2, which starts  at the middle of `idmapping`. Change `m=2` to `m=0`.